# Bluetooth connection after identifying if an application is present or not

Tags: android

Is it possible to connect 2 devices via bluetooth if one particular application is installed in both only.
I mean I would like the bluetooth  connection to be set up only if its recognized that "MY APP" is installed in both devices.
I have read that UUID is a random ID that depends on the device.Also something using Telephony Manager to get device id and serial ids.
But my need is not device specific.. its application specific.
Kindly help,Its really urgent

Answer (score 1):

For the 2 devices to check whether a specific condition is filled on both sides, they must do some kind of communication. From my point of view you will have to establish the connection, check if the app is installed, and abort if it is not the case.

Comment: how will i check if the app is installed or not?.. using the package name?